# Maven errors while compilling hadoop 2.4.0 on Ubunto 64 bits

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, hadoop2

I'm compilling hadoop 2.4.0 on Ubunto 64bit using Maven 
here is the information about versions of Maven and JDK

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I followed the tutorial bellow in github:

[Hadoop_64bits](https://github.com/y12studio/y12hadoop/blob/master/install-hadoop-2.4.0.md)

However, this command failed:

```
mvn clean package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

The error is:

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.466 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-07T12:52:44Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-os) on project hadoop-common: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

I could skip the phase of the maven-enforcer-plugin which I don't know if it is important or not in the hadoop compilation using an additionnal parametre:

```
 mvn clean package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Denforcer.skip=true
```

However I got this error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-os) on project hadoop-common: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Here is the contents of the file pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file. -->

-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>

<artifactId>hadoop-main</artifactId>

<version>2.4.0</version>

<description>Apache Hadoop Main</description>

<name>Apache Hadoop Main</name>

<packaging>pom</packaging>


-<dependencyManagement>


-<dependencies>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.cenqua.clover</groupId>

<artifactId>clover</artifactId>

<!-- Use the version needed by maven-clover-plugin -->


<version>3.0.2</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>


-<distributionManagement>


-<repository>

<id>${distMgmtStagingId}</id>

<name>${distMgmtStagingName}</name>

<url>${distMgmtStagingUrl}</url>

</repository>


-<snapshotRepository>

<id>${distMgmtSnapshotsId}</id>

<name>${distMgmtSnapshotsName}</name>

<url>${distMgmtSnapshotsUrl}</url>

</snapshotRepository>


-<site>

<id>apache.website</id>

<url>scpexe://people.apache.org/www/hadoop.apache.org/docs/r${project.version}</url>

</site>

</distributionManagement>


-<repositories>


-<repository>

<id>${distMgmtSnapshotsId}</id>

<name>${distMgmtSnapshotsName}</name>

<url>${distMgmtSnapshotsUrl}</url>

</repository>


-<repository>

<id>repository.jboss.org</id>

<url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>


-<snapshots>

<enabled>false</enabled>

</snapshots>

</repository>

</repositories>


-<licenses>


-<license>

<name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>

<url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>

</license>

</licenses>


-<organization>

<name>Apache Software Foundation</name>

<url>http://www.apache.org</url>

</organization>


-<properties>

<distMgmtSnapshotsId>apache.snapshots.https</distMgmtSnapshotsId>

<distMgmtSnapshotsName>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</distMgmtSnapshotsName>

<distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>

<distMgmtStagingId>apache.staging.https</distMgmtStagingId>

<distMgmtStagingName>Apache Release Distribution Repository</distMgmtStagingName>

<distMgmtStagingUrl>https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</distMgmtStagingUrl>

<!-- platform encoding override -->


<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

</properties>


-<modules>

<module>hadoop-project</module>

<module>hadoop-project-dist</module>

<module>hadoop-assemblies</module>

<module>hadoop-maven-plugins</module>

<module>hadoop-common-project</module>

<module>hadoop-hdfs-project</module>

<module>hadoop-yarn-project</module>

<module>hadoop-mapreduce-project</module>

<module>hadoop-tools</module>

<module>hadoop-dist</module>

<module>hadoop-client</module>

<module>hadoop-minicluster</module>

</modules>


-<build>


-<pluginManagement>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.4</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>

<version>1.3.1</version>


-<configuration>


-<rules>


-<requireMavenVersion>

<version>[3.0.2,)</version>

</requireMavenVersion>


-<requireJavaVersion>

<version>1.6</version>

</requireJavaVersion>

</rules>

</configuration>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.3</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.5</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>

<artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>

<version>0.7</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

<version>1.7</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>

<version>3.3</version>


-<dependencies>


-<dependency>

<!-- add support for ssh/scp -->


<groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>

<artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>

<version>1.0</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<!-- add support for markdown -->


<groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>

<artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>

<version>1.3</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>

<version>3.0.5</version>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.4.0</version>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</pluginManagement>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>

<inherited>false</inherited>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>clean</id>


-<goals>

<goal>enforce</goal>

</goals>

<phase>pre-clean</phase>

</execution>


-<execution>

<id>default</id>


-<goals>

<goal>enforce</goal>

</goals>

<phase>validate</phase>

</execution>


-<execution>

<id>site</id>


-<goals>

<goal>enforce</goal>

</goals>

<phase>pre-site</phase>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>

<artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>


-<configuration>


-<excludes>

<exclude>.gitattributes</exclude>

<exclude>.gitignore</exclude>

<exclude>.git/**</exclude>

<exclude>.idea/**</exclude>

</excludes>

</configuration>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>

<version>3.3</version>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>attach-descriptor</id>


-<goals>

<goal>attach-descriptor</goal>

</goals>


-<configuration>

<generateReports>true</generateReports>

</configuration>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>

<inherited>true</inherited>

<extensions>true</extensions>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>


-<reporting>

<excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.8.1</version>

<inherited>false</inherited>


-<reportSets>


-<reportSet>

<id>aggregate</id>


-<configuration>

<maxmemory>1024m</maxmemory>

<linksource>true</linksource>

<quiet>true</quiet>

<verbose>false</verbose>

<source>${maven.compile.source}</source>

<charset>${maven.compile.encoding}</charset>

<reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</reportOutputDirectory>

<destDir>hadoop-project/api</destDir>

<!-- Non-public APIs -->


<excludePackageNames>org.apache.hadoop.authentication*,org.apache.hadoop.hdfs*,org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server*,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp*</excludePackageNames>


-<groups>


-<group>

<title>Common</title>

<packages>org.apache.hadoop*</packages>

</group>


-<group>

<title>MapReduce</title>

<packages>org.apache.hadoop.mapred*</packages>

</group>


-<group>

<title>YARN</title>

<packages>org.apache.hadoop.yarn*</packages>

</group>

</groups>

<doclet>org.apache.hadoop.classification.tools.IncludePublicAnnotationsStandardDoclet</doclet>


-<docletArtifacts>


-<docletArtifact>

<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>

<artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>

<version>${project.version}</version>

</docletArtifact>

</docletArtifacts>

<useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>

<!-- switch on dependency-driven aggregation -->


<includeDependencySources>false</includeDependencySources>


-<dependencySourceIncludes>

<!-- include ONLY dependencies I control -->


<dependencySourceInclude>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations</dependencySourceInclude>

</dependencySourceIncludes>

</configuration>


-<reports>

<report>aggregate</report>

</reports>

</reportSet>

</reportSets>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.4</version>


-<reportSets>


-<reportSet>


-<reports>

<report>analyze-report</report>

</reports>

</reportSet>

</reportSets>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</reporting>


-<profiles>


-<profile>

<id>src</id>


-<activation>

<activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>

</activation>


-<build>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

<inherited>false</inherited>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>src-dist</id>

<phase>package</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>single</goal>

</goals>


-<configuration>

<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

<attach>false</attach>

<finalName>hadoop-${project.version}-src</finalName>

<outputDirectory>hadoop-dist/target</outputDirectory>

<!-- Not using descriptorRef and hadoop-assembly dependency -->


<!-- to avoid making hadoop-main to depend on a module -->



-<descriptors>

<descriptor>hadoop-assemblies/src/main/resources/assemblies/hadoop-src.xml</descriptor>

</descriptors>

</configuration>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

<inherited>false</inherited>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>src-dist-msg</id>

<phase>package</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>run</goal>

</goals>


-<configuration>


-<target>

<echo/>

<echo>Hadoop source tar available at: ${basedir}/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-${project.version}-src.tar.gz</echo>

<echo/>

</target>

</configuration>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</profile>


-<profile>

<id>dist</id>

<!-- Profile for generating all maven artifacts and documentation. -->



-<build>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

<inherited>false</inherited>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<!-- build aggregate javadoc in parent only -->


<id>default-cli</id>


-<goals>

<goal>aggregate</goal>

</goals>


-<configuration>

<overview>hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/overview.html</overview>

</configuration>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</profile>


-<profile>

<id>sign</id>


-<build>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>sign-artifacts</id>

<phase>verify</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>sign</goal>

</goals>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</profile>


-<profile>

<id>clover</id>


-<activation>

<activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>


-<property>

<name>clover</name>

</property>

</activation>


-<properties>

<cloverLicenseLocation>${user.home}/.clover.license</cloverLicenseLocation>

<cloverDatabase>${project.build.directory}/clover/hadoop-coverage.db</cloverDatabase>

<!-- NB: This additional parametrization is made in order to be able to re-define these properties with "-Dk=v" maven options. By some reason the expressions declared in clover docs like "${maven.clover.generateHtml}" do not work in that way. However, the below properties are confirmed to work: e.g. -DcloverGenHtml=false switches off the Html generation. The default values provided here exactly correspond to Clover defaults, so the behavior is 100% backwards compatible. -->


<cloverAlwaysReport>true</cloverAlwaysReport>

<cloverGenHtml>true</cloverGenHtml>

<cloverGenXml>true</cloverGenXml>

<cloverGenHistorical>false</cloverGenHistorical>

</properties>


-<build>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>


-<configuration>

<includesAllSourceRoots>false</includesAllSourceRoots>

<includesTestSourceRoots>true</includesTestSourceRoots>

<licenseLocation>${cloverLicenseLocation}</licenseLocation>

<cloverDatabase>${cloverDatabase}</cloverDatabase>

<targetPercentage>50%</targetPercentage>

<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/clover</outputDirectory>

<alwaysReport>${cloverAlwaysReport}</alwaysReport>

<generateHtml>${cloverGenHtml}</generateHtml>

<generateXml>${cloverGenXml}</generateXml>

<generateHistorical>${cloverGenHistorical}</generateHistorical>


-<excludes>

<exclude>**/examples/**/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/hamlet/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/ha/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/protocol/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/compiler/generated/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/protobuf/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/v2/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/yarn/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/security/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/tools/proto/*.java</exclude>

<exclude>**/hs/proto/*.java</exclude>

</excludes>

</configuration>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<id>clover-setup</id>

<phase>process-sources</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>setup</goal>

</goals>

</execution>


-<execution>

<id>clover</id>

<phase>test</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>clover</goal>

</goals>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</profile>

</profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: I would grep thru the parent POMS to find the rules that failed and see what can be done to remedy the problem.

Comment: @RichDuncan I've added the contents of the parent POMS

Comment: The link to 64 Hadoop references an item that is 4 years old.  So, for example, it uses JDK 7 not 8 and uses an older version of Maven (3.0.4) and an older version of Ubuntu and you have to build protobuf from source.  You may have to downgrade a few things in order to get the build to work.

Comment: @Rich Duncan I followed all the steps and I downloaded the same versions as in this example except maven which I downloaded the latest version, so I will try to downgrade it!

Comment: it looks like your Linux is a different version as well.

Comment: If you just want Hadoop, you should be building the latest stable version

Comment: @cricket_007 No I need to install Giraph which seems very sensitive to versions

Comment: I don't think Giraph is really worked on anymore compared to JanusGraph or GraphX, but regarding this question, you've cut off the important information `Look above for specific messages` is not the beginning of the error